# Finding GPUImage framework headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, gpuimage

I'm trying to implement GPUImage into my iOS application but I'm running into a problem. On the [GitHub page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for the framework under the *Adding the static library to your iOS project* section, it says:

> You'll also need to find the framework headers, so within your project's build settings set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the GPUImage source directory. Make this header search path recursive.

I've found the Header Search Paths setting and I've set the search path to recursive, but I'm not sure what path to actually input so the framework functions properly. What do I need to input here (explained in relatively simple terms) and how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for by following an online tutorial. All I needed was to input the pathway from my Xcode project folder to the GPUImage directory.